# how to evaluate prefix expression for with logical operator

Tags: algorithm, operators, prefix

I have a prefix expression with multiple AND and OR operators, creating a level of more than 1, The algorithm I wrote working fine for single depth but screwing up the result for depth of more than 1. I'm using python

Prefix list: -  `['OR', 'AND', '=', ['.', 'grade'], 12, '>=', ['.', 'gpa'], ['.', '$', 'GPA'], 'AND', '=', ['.', 'a'], ['.', 'b'], '>', ['.', 'c'], ['.', 'd']]`

```
def prefix_evaluation(prefix_list):
    opstack = []
    operand_stk = []
    pending_opd = False
    for token in prefix_list:
        if token in operators:
            opstack.append(token)
            pending_opd = False
        else:
            operand = token
            if pending_opd:
                while len(operand_stk) > 0:
                    opd_1 = operand_stk.pop()
                    operator  = opstack.pop()
                    operand = [operator, opd_1, operand]
            operand_stk.append(operand)
            pending_opd = True
    return operand_stk.pop()
```

Expected Result:

```
[ OR,
    [ AND,
         [ AND,
              [ '=', ['.', 'grade'], 12],
              [ '>=', ['.', 'gpa'], ['.', '$', 'GPA']]
         ]
         [ AND,
              ['=', ['.', 'a'], ['.', 'b']],
              ['>', ['.', 'c'], ['.', 'd']]
         ]
    ]
]
```

Actual Result:

```
['OR',
     ['AND', 
           ['AND', 
                ['=', ['.', 'grade'], 12], 
                ['>=', ['.', 'gpa'], 
                ['.', '$', 'GPA']]], 
           ['=', ['.', 'a'], ['.', 'b']]],
     ['>', ['.', 'c'], ['.', 'd']]]
```

Comment: Throw it all away and look up recursive descent expression parsing or the Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the list more readable, i have replaced with `n` all the operands such as `12`, `['.', 'grade']`, `['.', 'c']` and so on. Also, i have replaced with `=` all the arithmetic operators such as `'>='`, `'>'`.

Now your list looks like `OR    AND  = n n   = n n   AND  = n n   = n n`

I have used round, square, curly brackets to emphasize how the terms group together - or should have grouped toghether

[image]

`(= n n)` is actually  a list consisting of one operator and two operands, such as `['>=', 12, 12]`

a graphical perspective that shows the differences between the expected and the actual result is the following:
[image]

by the moment the program has parsed the sub-list `OR  AND = n n  = n n` , it will have formed the operand `[AND (= n n) (= n n)]` ( along with the extra `OR` which is still in operators stack). As you can see, this operand is common to both the expected and the actual results.

by the moment the program has parsed the sub-list `OR   AND = n n  = n n   AND = n n` (note the extra `AND  = n n` ), it will have the already formed `[AND (= n n) (= n n)]` operand, along with the new operator `AND` and operand `(=n n)` . Which it will group as  `{AND   [AND (= n n) (= n n)]   (= n n) }` . That's what the program does, the way it is written. There is really now way of telling your program : hey, there's a second `[AND (= n n) (= n n)]` that needs to be formed, and only then concatenate the two with the `OR` .

To give an analogy, this is like expecting a parser that reads character by character to realize that 1+2*3 is not (1+2)*3, but 1+(2*3), unless you specify somehow that multiplication has higher precedence over addition.

The pitfall here is that you are putting in the same basket both arithmetic and logical operators. No wonder they have the same precedence (priority) when building expressions.

A better approach would be to differentiate between arithmetic expressions like 
`(= n n)` and logical expressions like `[AND E1 E2]`, by putting them in two different stacks, along with a 3rd stack for basic operands like `n`. Also put the arithmetic operators like `=` in a different stack from the logical operators like `AND`. And only now you can impose the rule that **the 'AND' operator should only link two arithmetical or two logical expressions, but not one arithmetical with one logical expression**, so as to avoid your current output and get the expected one.

But i feel that the stack approach is cumbersome, better use recursion as someone suggested.